# How do I continue the input to fprintf on the next line?

Tags: matlab

Given the following code:

```
fprintf('test test',...
        'test');
```

I get the following output on my terminal:

> test test

How can I continue on to the next line for `fprintf`?

Answer (score 4):

The issue has nothing to do with the line continuation characters.

Only the [format specifier](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) string (the first or second input) is processed unless a format operator is provided in that format specifier string.

```
fprintf('test test %s', ...
        'test');
```

If you instead want to concatenate strings, you should use `[]` to create a string across multiple lines that you then pass to `fprintf` as the format specifier.

```
fprintf(['test test ', ...
        'test'])
```

If you want the last `'test'` to appear on a new line, then you should use the newline control sequence to specify that you'd like it on a new line

```
fprintf('test test\ntest')
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
fprintf('test test\ntest')
```

"\n" is interpreted as new line character (Ascii 10), this behavior is similar to printf in c and many other languages.

Read about  [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)